# Prepare Setup For C# Windows Application

Tags: c#, windows, installation

I've a windows application project developed in c# and VS2010 environment. Now I need to prepare a setup for it. I've prepared it via creating "setup project" within VS2010 and it works fine.

The problem is, when I wanted to migrate my project to VS2012, I noticed that Microsoft is no longer supporting "setup projects" inside VS2012 anymore. InstallShield technology seems to appear.

My question is, has anyone tried to use an existing setup project which is created by VS2010 in VS2012? Does it work? Any problems? Is that still supported for VS2012?

By the way, I researched in web and found out that WiX is another solution for preperation on setups. Does anyone use that? Can I integrate my VS2010 .SLN file into ViX? Will that work when I migrate my project to VS2012? If so, how?

My project will be commercial so that any another well 3rd party solutions are fine by me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should migrate to WiX, as it is available both for Visual Studio 2010 and the later versions of Visual Studio. It also creates MSI installers and is much more customizable than the setups created by the Visual Studio 2010 template.

Actually it is the other way: You don't integrate a solution with WiX, but a WiX installation project will be just like any other project in your solution. Pretty much the same a with the Visual Studio setup project type.